# Имя переменной внутри переменной и массивы

Tags: php

```
$a='b';
$$a="c";
echo $b;
$$a=array();
$$a[0]='One';
print_r($b);
```

Почему не создаётся массив $b ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы php понял, что вы хотите, напишите ему понятно :)

```
${$a}[0]='One';
```

получится

```
Array ( [0] => One )
```

Answer (score 2):

Массив не создается потому что строка

```
$$a[0]='One';
```

Трактуется как

```
${$a[0]}='One';
```

Так как `$a = 'b'`, то `$a[0] = 'b'` и получается что `$b ='One'`;

Если вам надо добавить именно в `$$a`

```
array_push($$a, 'One');
```

Comment: Спасибо , разъяснили. Только array_push меня не устраивает. В моём случае массив вообще двухмерный типа $$a[0][1]